# What is the difference between System.Linq and System.Data.Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was having troubles earlier while trying to declare a ChangeAction parameter in a method, with the IDE saying I might be missing a Namespace.

So I right click it and Resolve it and find that System.Data.Linq has been added and now everything is fine.

What is the difference between these two namespaces?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I understand it, System.Linq is about the overall Linq library -- it applies to all data types like Lists and such.

System.Data.Linq is about databases (aka Linq to SQL), which includes tracking changes (ChangeAction).

Answer (score 9):

I believe `System.Linq` is LINQ-OBJECTS specific (IEnumerable, IQueryable, etc)

Whilst `System.Data.Lin`q is LINQ-SQL specific (DataContext, etc)

Answer (score 3):

As described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.aspx

System.Data.Linq is for accessing relational data

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, System.Linq is generic-level implementation which relies on
IEnumerable whereas System.Data.Linq is provider-specific (LINQ to SQL) which relies on IQueryable.